# How to print client's original post string to the log when meeting HttpMessageNotReadableException in sprintmvc

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, tomcat, jackson

When I post a valid JSON to Spring MVC, it works well. But If the json is missing a quote or otherwise invalid. The server will throw an exception named `HttpMessageNotReadableException` with some useful information, but it doesn't show the JSON that was sent, which is what testers need to know.

For example, post an invalid JSON string: (Missing a quotes after the "code" property)

```
{
    "problemid": "1",
    "language": 1,
    "code": test",
    "userid": "s1001",
    "otherid": "test01",
    "access_token": "de96a12-1c1f-40b9-8e2a-a3b86c17fd31"
}
```

The server log error is:

```
Could not read document: Unexpected character ('#' (code 35)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unexpected character ('#' (code 35)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@fe0bb0e; line: 4, column: 14]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('#' (code 35)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@fe0bb0e; line: 4, column: 14]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('#' (code 35)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@fe0bb0e; line: 4, column: 14]
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@fe0bb0e; line: 4, column: 14]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:229)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('#' (code 35)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@fe0bb0e; line: 4, column: 14]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1586)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:521)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:450)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2628)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextFieldName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1069)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:348)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:133)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3807)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2881)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:226)
    ... 47 more
```

How can I print the client's whole post JSON string to the log also?